# Can I get Improved Grapple without having Improved Unarmed Strike?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, grapple

I want to have [Improved Grapple](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-grapple-combat---final) for my character, but a prerequisite is to have [Improved Unarmed Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-unarmed-strike-combat---final).

Is there any way to get IG without having the IUS feat? I know some classes / archtypes gets IUS as a bonus feat, but it's not one of the classes / archtypes I want to play.

I'm aming towards Savage Technologist (2lvl) / Rogue Cutpurse (3lvl). But I'm open to suggestions. I don't want to (or cannot) play Monk, Unarmed Fighter or Monastic Magus Archetype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think that there are any ways to get it without using the three classes you listed. I would suggest just spending a feat on it, or (if your build is very feat-starved) taking the rogue talent "combat trick" for an additional feat. If you're willing to stray from the build you mentioned, a cleric of Irori (or any other deity with unarmed strike as a favored weapon) gets improved unarmed strike for free (though that would be very different then what you had in mind stat-wise). Depending on your sources, there might be other options, but as far as I am aware (and I have most paizo pathfinder material) it isn't viable as a class/race ability.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, there is a way to do it.**

The [Dirty Fighting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/dirty-fighting-combat) feat ([Dirty Tactics Toolbox](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1601257635)) counts as both [Improved Unarmed Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-unarmed-strike-combat---final) and [Combat Expertise](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/combat-expertise-combat) for the purpose of feat prerequisites, among other things.